# Using dropzone to save multiple images that have relation with article

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I'm building a website in which the user can create articles with multiple images. Of Course that images will have relation with article.

All works good using laravel (php) and mysql. The database has the relation of images and articles.

Now I would like to add a new feature so as the user can upload or remove image from article so I thought to use dropzone library.

Now using dropzone there is one big problem. The dropzone upload the images on the server without any problem, but then when I click the submit button to save the article I would like to get again that images so I can make the relation with article. 
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: One possibility is to save IDs to user session and load them by ID( if you save path to DB)